# String to array with condition checking

Tags: php, arrays, string

The string has a html content.

For example:

```
<ul> 
  <li>....</li>
  <li>....</li> 
  <li>....</li> 
</ul>
```

Is there any function in php that can convert a string to an array like this

```
array(
  [0] => '<ul>',
  [1] => '<li>....</li>',
  [2] => '<li>....</li>',
  [3] => '</ul>'
)
```

can any one guide me.

Comment: You can achieve it using explode(), preg_match() or many more..

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: see below answers for solution

Comment: $myString = "<ul> 
  <li>....</li>
  <li>....</li> 
  <li>....</li> 
</ul>"; $myArray = explode("\n",$myString);

Answer (score 0):

```
$a='<ul> 
<li>....</li>
<li>....</li> 
<li>....</li> 
</ul>';


$as = explode("\n", $a);
print_r($as);
```

then

```
Array
(
    [0] => <ul> 
    [1] => <li>....</li>
    [2] => <li>....</li> 
    [3] => <li>....</li> 
    [4] => </ul>
)
```

Comment: thanks dude.. But my string is like $a=<ul><li>....</li><li>....</li> <li>....</li></ul>' ... At this how i can implement ?

Answer (score 0):

`$str` is your original string.

```
$array = explode("\n", $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're actually trying to do.

If you're actually trying to separate the string by lines, its fairly easy:

```
$array = explode("\n", $htmlString);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = trim($value);
}

print_r($array); // Use this to dump out the value of $array.
```

However, if you're trying to parse the HTML in a meaningful way, then it's not so easy. You'll want to use DOMDocument or a dedicated HTML/XML parser instead.

For the reason why, read this:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleXML for parse the HTML and later convert it to array

```
$result = (array) simplexml_load_string($htmlDocument);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

```
$ul = <<<HTML
<ul> 
  <li>....</li>
  <li>....</li> 
  <li>....</li> 
</ul>
HTML;

$result = (array) simplexml_load_string($ul);

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need a html praser for generic solution

try the links
http://code.google.com/p/php-html2array/

to download the class file
http://code.google.com/p/php-html2array/downloads/detail?name=class.htmlParser%20v1.02.zip&can=2&q=